# grub .cfg goes on for pages long?

Tags: 16.04, boot, grub2, performance

My laptop takes two and a bit  minutes to boot. I wait over 90 seconds before all the services start to load and fsck runs before that happens.

Hi, thanks, Byte Commander. I see what you mean. I've put the output of analyze blame and analyze here. Hope you can help.

```
Startup finished in 15.943s (kernel) + 1min 45.912s (userspace) = 2min 1.855s
johnny@donkeykong:~$ systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20
         51.863s apt-daily.service
         19.344s dev-sda1.device
         13.907s ModemManager.service
         13.384s snapd.service
         12.915s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          9.962s apt-daily-upgrade.service
          9.078s apparmor.service
          6.891s grub-common.service
          6.245s irqbalance.service
          5.992s apport.service
          5.688s ondemand.service
          5.427s lm-sensors.service
          5.369s systemd-logind.service
          5.296s ufw.service
          5.134s alsa-restore.service
          5.117s rsyslog.service
          5.106s systemd-user-sessions.service
          5.104s zram-config.service
          4.799s NetworkManager.service
          4.768s avahi-daemon.service
```

Comment: That file size for `grub.cfg` is totally normal and fine. Besides, it's written in capital letters at the top if it that you're not supposed to edit it. Why do you even think the problem lies here? GRUB is only the initial boot loader with the pink menu. As soon as that is gone, GRUB has exited and Ubuntu took over the boot process. Can [edit] your question and add the output of `systemd-analyze` and `systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20` instead of that config file please?

Comment: Hi. OK, thanks for that. Here are the outputs of analyze and analyze-blame head -n 20. It would be great if you could help me with this  issue.